# What's a good JS graph library that has a good-looking radar graph?

Tags: javascript, graph

I've looked at many graphing libraries and couldn't find one with a good radar graph. See image for the type of look I want. Most of the one's I've seen look very plain and mathy, anything that could be used for a game interface?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

- https://github.com/tnzk/Raphael-Radar
- Example: http://www.tnzk.org/devel/Raphael-Radar/example/

It uses Raphael.js, and you can improve it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

i am using this one

https://github.com/jsoma/raphael-radar

its pretty easy to customize and works with rapahael js